# Scaling Kafka Streams applications

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a streaming application that reads data from a topic. For every message on the topic it will:

- map the key from installationid:assetId:modelId to installationId:assetId:modelId:tag
- group by key
- window by 15 minutes
- reduce to determine and keep the max value of all messages in the window

`Materialized<String, ErrorScore, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>> materialized = 
    Materialized
                .as("store");`

```
stream
      .map((s, myObject) -> new KeyValue<>(s + "::" + myObject.getT(),
            new ErrorScore(myObject.getTs(), myObject.getE(), myObject.getO())))
            .groupByKey()
            .windowedBy(configuredTimeWindows)
            .reduce((aggValue, newValue) -> getMaxErrorScore(aggValue, 
             newValue), materialized);
```

In the end I will end up with:

```
1551168000 1234:a:v1  0.1
1551168900 1234:a:v1  0.2
1551169800 1234:a:v1  0.1
```

So there are three windows where there is a key and the max value of all the messages that fall in the boundaries of a window.

Then I have a rest endpoint that is used to query the data in the state store / changelogs using metadata. This means that I will utilize the

```
InteractiveQueryService.getHostInfo()
```

to see if a certain key is on the current host, or that the information is to be find on a different host.

The issue I'm now running into is the following: Everytime I invoke the rest endpoint, it will have to determine by key if the requested data is on this host or a remote host. if the data is not found on this host, it will invoke a rest endpoint for that single key. As I'm interested in 200 keys, this will cause me to create 200 connections to gather data spread over different instances. This is taking too much time unfortunately.

I tried to come up with a solution like using a more coarse grained key, for instance just installationId:assetId:modelId and thereby leaving the tag out of the key. This however results in not being able to determine the max value per model.

any idea how to cope with this?

Comment: Instead of doing each call to a remove host with a new connection, it should be sufficient to have one connected between each pair of hosts and reuse the same connection for multiple keys.

Comment: Driving to the office made me think of this solution as well! thanks a lot Matthias!